# How to change a column width for print vs. screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.2

I've created a two column layout (vertical sidebar menu, and main content area).

The Vertical sidebar uses a css class of `.col-sm-3 hidden-print`, and the main content is `.col-sm-9`

When the page is printed I would like the class on the main content area to change to `.col-sm-12` (for just the print media).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.
Add class **col-print-12** to your **col-sm-9** class.
Then add this to your css:

```
@media print {
    .col-print-12 { width: 100% }
}
```

Comment: ah.  very good.  thanks.  I think `col-print-12` or `print-12` is a slightly better name than `.print-9`.

Comment: Damn, you're right! I better change my answer.